# Android: Device position after Service starts

Tags: java, android, xml, adk

I am here with another Android connected problem. In my testing application I create simple Service implements SensorEventListener to deal with Accelerometer.

This Service should get current device position and next time test, if the device did not move. I tried to do it like this (pseudocode):

```
  onStart() {
    registerListener(listener, accelerometer, SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    unregisterListener();
  }
```

Listener is class sub class defined like this:

```
class DefaultValuesListener implements SensorEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    lastX = event.values[0];
    lastY = event.values[0];
    return;
    }
}
```

Then I test the movement in Services function onSensorChanged. I find out that `lastX` and `lastY` are still equal zero. Position is not set.

I know I should do test whenever default values were set and if not, then set them in Services onSensorChanged, but it is last possible solution.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (!defaultPosSet) {
        lastX = event.values[0];
        lastY = event.values[0];
    } else {
        // DO test there ...
    }
}
```

Is there better one?

**Edit:** 
Since noone reply to this question, I will use this code:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (!defaultPosSet) {
        lastX = event.values[0];
        lastY = event.values[0];
    } else {
        // DO test there ...
    }
}
```